# Value in dropdown that doesnt exist

Tags: excel

I have create a chart which pulls information from a pivot table.

One of the fields I am pulling in is the month. During the testing I added January February and March.

I have now populated the table with live data which includes January and February but March is still showing up in the drop down menu even though it has been removed from the table.

If I delete the table, I get three blank options.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In order to remove items that have been deleted to the data source...*

1. Right click on Pivot Table
2. Select `Pivot Table Options...`
3. Select '`Data` Tab
4. Change `Number of items to retain per field` to **None**

---

Once you refresh the pivot table, old values that are no longer present in the data source will be dropped. I usually turn this back to automatic after dropping unwanted fields although this depends on your use case

[image]